# T-sql substring function to extract specific string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am trying to extract the date in @value variable as below.

```
Declare @value nvarchar(61)= 'Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 12/5/2014 1:00:13 PM from ATOM.'

Select SUBSTRING(@value,43,len(@value))
```

But the gotcha is that 'radomemail@xyzdomain.com' is variable, there by shifting the start index from 43

Is there a better way to do this, i would prefer a way where start position of substring will start from last index of @value, and count back.

Comment: The constants is also more then 61 characters...

Comment: I *really* would consider using an ISO-8601 date format to make sure each date and time length is standardised an reconginsed independent of local setting. I'm British and your date/time format is frankly nonsense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @value nvarchar(100)= 'Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 12/5/2014 1:00:13 PM from ATOM.'

Select LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(RTRIM(@value)), 31)),20)
```

Now boys and girls, a solution for all date formats as well as variable length suffixes

```
Declare @values table (value nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);

INSERT @values VALUES
    ('Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 2/2/2014 1:00:13 PM from ATOM.'),
    ('Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 17/2/2014 1:00:13 PM from SOmewhere.'),
    ('Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 2/11/2014 1:00:13 PM from NeverNeverLand.'),
    ('Generated by radomemail@xyzdomain.com on 12/11/2014 1:00:13 PM from X.')


SELECT
    RTRIM(SUBSTRING(V.value, PATINDEX(X.Pattern, V.value)+1, X.Patlength))
FROM
    @values V
    JOIN
    (
    VALUES
        ('% [1-9]/[1-9]/2[0-3][0-9][0-9]%', 20),
        ('% [1-3][0-9]/[1-9]/2[0-3][0-9][0-9]%', 21),
        ('% [1-9]/1[0-2]/2[0-3][0-9][0-9]%', 21),
        ('% [1-3][0-9]/1[0-2]/2[0-][0-9][0-9]%', 22)
    ) X (Pattern, Patlength) ON PATINDEX(X.Pattern, V.value) > 0
```

Comment: THANKS GBN, THAT WORKED ! VOTING THIS UP!

Comment: This doesn't work. What if the date is `12/12/2004`?

Comment: Or even `1/1/2004` or could the year be double digit?

Comment: @OKonkwoIkechukwuEdwin Check my answer, it copes with other formats.

Comment: @DavidG: The original substring length needs to be 20 or 21 or 22 as a consequence of not using ISO-8601 dates. I've updated the solution as a T-SQL exercise

Answer (score 1):

Use CHARINDEX to find the string `on`, then use that as the start point, then do the same to remove the text after `from`:

```
Select SUBSTRING(@value,CHARINDEX(' on ', @value)+4,CHARINDEX(' from ', SUBSTRING(@value,CHARINDEX(' on ', @value)+4,len(@value))))
```

Comment: This also deals with times too

Comment: @gbn Indeed, I replicated the results from the OPs original query.

Comment: Easy to fix though, just ignore it.